# Python: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, ''))

Tags: python, proxy, request, python-requests

I try to get content from a lot of urls. The part of data looks like

```
avito.ru/morozovsk/avtomobili/honda_accord_1998_799656153
avito.ru/donetck/avtomobili/honda_accord_2000_829068734
avito.ru/donetck/avtomobili/honda_accord_2000_829068734
avito.ru/taganrog/avtomobili/volkswagen_passat_1997_839237476
avito.ru/volgodonsk/avtomobili/volkswagen_golf_1993_657720225
avito.ru/volgodonsk/avtomobili/volkswagen_golf_1993_657720225
avito.ru/volgodonsk/avtomobili/volkswagen_golf_1993_657720225
avito.ru/volgodonsk/avtomobili/volkswagen_golf_1993_657720225
avito.ru/taganrog/avtomobili/peugeot_206_2008_818743294
```

I use

```
    url = 'https://' + url
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    page = response.content
```

But in the middle of the processing it returns me an error `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, ''))`.
I tried to use `time.sleep(10)` to solve this problem. but it didn't help.
What should I use to solve this? maybe proxies can help me?

Comment: What url caused the error or is it different each time?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It different each time

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I have had this a few times, adding a sleep did not matter either, I just had a method with a try/except that caught the error, I waited 30 seconds and kept trying in a while loop at most five times then sleeping again if not successful and logging any errors.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and error will dissapear?

Comment: No it won't disappear, you need to catch the error and retry but doing so should get through all your urls.